# How to include Vue plugins to Vue TypeScript's template?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-meta

How to include Vue plugins to Vue TypeScript's template, like [vue-webpack-typescript](https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript)?

For example, [vue-meta](https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta).

I already add to `./src/main.ts` this:

```
import * as Meta from 'vue-meta';

Vue.use(Meta, {
  keyName: 'head', 
  attribute: 'data-vue-meta', 
  ssrAttribute: 'data-vue-meta-ssr', 
  tagIDKeyName: 'vmid'
});
```

And add this to `./src/components/home/home.ts` component:

```
export class HomeComponent extends Vue {

  static head() {
    return {
      title: 'Test'
    }
  }

}
```

But this not working, don't show over written title..

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with including Vue plugins I suppose.
If you correctly set typescript compiler to work with vue, the component would use whatever the plugins are. So I guess it would be the issue of your using the class-style component.

According to the Vue's official example, you'll need `vue-class-component` to make Vue recognize class components.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components

```
@Component
export class MyMixin extends Vue {
  mixinValue = 'Hello'
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write this in Component decorator:

```
@Component({
  head () {
    return {
      title: 'test'
    }
  }
})
export class Test extends Vue {}
```